# Count up to 1000000 with javascript with img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an image of all number from 0 to 9. I want to count up from 0 to 1000000 with `img` tag. For example `if number == 1` position of img tag would be `top = 100px`

```
var count = 0;
var counter = function() {

    if (count == 1000) {
        count = +1;
        $(".number-inner").text(count);
    }
    count++;
    $(".number-inner").text(count);
    setTimeout(counter, 10)
}



setTimeout(counter, 1000)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: count up to 1000000 with img tag

Comment: instead of number img tag change by value

Comment: You've got a command to reset the number at 1000, should that be 1000000? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: oops this is a mistake sorry for that

Comment: there is no need to reset

Answer (score 3):

Hi you need to cut your image to 9 images, so it will be each image have a number then you can name the image with number, for example the image who had number 4 name it `4.png` .... Here is my code and project folder to see what i did

code:

```
    var i=0, j=0;
    var count = setInterval(function(){
    if(i!=9){
      i++;
    }
    else{
        j++;
        i=0;
    }
    $('.stop').html(j+''+i).hide();
    $('.counter').html('<img src='+j+'.png><img src='+i+'.png>');
    if($('.stop').html()==14)
        clearInterval(count);
},1000);
```

just remove 14 to 10000 ( or whatever you want )

image:
[image]

result ( the counter stop at number 14 ):

[image]

hope my answer usefull

Comment: thanks for your answer John , but i need to have all number in one image for not having blink in counting .

Comment: but that was a nice solution